# Kubernetes spread pods along nodepools

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a managed kubernetes cluster in GCP, which has 2 node pools - one on regular VMs, one on spot VMs, autoscaling is configured for both of them.
Currently i'm running batch jobs and async tasks on spot VMs and web apps on regular VMs, but to reduce costs i'd like to move web apps pods mostly to spot VMS. Usually i have 3-5 pods of each app running, so i'd like to leave 1 on regular VMs and 2-4 move to spot.

I've found a `nodeAffinity` and `podAffinity` settings and have set preferred pod placement with `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` and spot VMs node selector, but now all my pods have moved to spot VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: topology.kubernetes.io/type
            operator: In
            values:
            - regular
            - spot/preemptible
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: 
      - weight: 100  
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app 
              operator: In 
              values:
              - app-label
          topologyKey: spot-node-label
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i get all pods scheduled to spot nodes this way